# Why did Togusa's family computer buy Cerano Genomics stock by itself?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In episode 14, Section 9 discovered a program that kept making money for the man who died four months ago. At the end of the episode, Togusa is seen with his wife talking about how she gained 100K yen from buying Meditech stock a while back. Then she turns off the computer, and together they leave the room. After that, their computer turns back on, buys 80K of Cerano Genomics stock, and turns off.

[image: animated GIF of scene described above]

Was it the dead man's program that did this? Is this how it made money? Or was it something else?

Comment: That's the implication certainly (in response to Togusa "paying the ferryman" when they remove the body), and what I believe, but I don't have any proof.

Answer (score 5):

I will move this to comment, when I'm able.

Notice the [mouse] cursor being moved to the "purchase" button. This is clearly an individual and not software. The user also scrolls through the list to find the Cerano entry where software would index and select the entry directly from an array or list in memory and not with the mouse.

Comment: I have considerable programming background, and it's hard for me to believe this was absolutely necessary for the browser to be visible throughout this operation, and the cursor to be used for clicking buttons. This might have been necessary to let the viewers understand what is really going on. It would not mean anything to them, if the computer just froze for half a second (if even for so long), executing a few simple web requests. These days viruses can do internet data exchange without even the best antivirus software noticing, let alone people. This is an interesting theory nevertheless.

Comment: True, it could be just a visual clue for the viewer. Also, it could be that the virus chose to "inhabit" a body and use the mouse rather than interface directly.

Comment: If the software wants to leave no trails it has to look like user action, so there's no way around performing the actual user-action. If the request was made by a script it could be found out by simply analyzing how fast the requests were made and that's our world, not the future displayed within that show.